# adb -s 192.168.1.6:5555 ..... error: more than one device/emulator

Tags: android, react-native, adb

I am working with react native, and would like to switch adb to wifi for easier debugging.

I connect my device using usb, then type these commands.

```
adb tcpip 5555
```

Then I disconnect my usb cable and enter this command

```
adb connect 192.168.1.6
connected to 192.168.1.6:5555
```

adb devices result in the following

```
adb devices
List of devices attached
192.168.1.6:5555        device
```

So it only shows one device connected.
However trying this command

```
adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
```

gives me the following error even though only one device is shown with adb devices command as shown above

```
error: more than one device/emulator
```

So I tried this command but I also get the same error

```
adb -s 192.168.1.6:5555 reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
error: more than one device/emulator
```

Trying the following gives me the same error

```
adb -s "192.168.1.6:5555" reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
adb -s "192.168.1.6" reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
adb -s 192.168.1.6 reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
```

even trying to use the device id which I copied when it was connected to usb resulted in the same error

```
adb -s deviceid reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
```

Is there a way to make adb reverse work when adb is connected wireless?

Thanks for advance.

Comment: Can you `adb shell` ? Did you try `adb kill-server` and `adb start-server`? Which version do you have? (`adb version`) Check https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb

Comment: @lojza adb shell works, but inside the shell 'reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081' doesn't work.it tells me reverse not found.
Adb version Version 4797878
I tried killing and starting

Comment: same as [Adb reverse tcp not working on android connected remotely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46138780/adb-reverse-tcp-not-working-on-android-connected-remotely)

Comment: I'm interessted in the same, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

I made two changes to the steps to get this working.

1) **BEFORE disconnecting the wire** from my phone, I ran `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:5555` (note the `5555` port number for the phone) and `adb connect`MY.PHONE.IP.ADDRESS:5555` (with port number).

**Only now did I disconnect the wire.**

Then I installed the app, although it probably would work if the app was already installed.

2) After the app was installed and I was getting errors "Unable to load Script” and “Could not connect to development server”,

- opened the developer menu (shake the phone with the React Native app open) and selected “Dev Settings”. Selected “Debug server host & port for device” from the menu.
- In the window on my phone I entered `MY.COMPUTER.IP.ADDRESS:8081`

Now I could open/close the app for a reload, and shake -> debug JS remotely.

Answer (score 1):

When I am facing the same issues than doing like below:

1) kill your process of 8081 port for using this command : `kill -9 $(lsof -t -i:8081)`

2) Reset your adb connection with : `adb usb` if you want to run via wifi then connect your device again : `adb tcpip 5555`

3) Start your npm : `npm start`

4) Then after you can run your react native app : `react-native run-android`

and it's works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

Simple, 
Start task manager 
and kill adb.exe process 
and run 
adb devices
command