# React Native adb reverse error: more than one device

Tags: android, react-native, adb

I am learning react native. I can successfully connect my android device using USB. But when I try to connect it using wifi, it gives me an error.

```
$ adb kill-server      
$ adb version
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.40
Version 4986621
Installed as /home/subtleseeker/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb          
$ adb connect 172.26.40.211:8081

* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
connected to 172.26.40.211:8081
$ adb devices                   
List of devices attached
172.26.40.211:8081      device

$ react-native run-android
JS server already running.
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew installDebug)...
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible and 1 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
cache results.bin (/home/subtleseeker/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/metadata-1.1/results.bin) is corrupt. Discarding.

> Task :app:installDebug 
Installing APK 'app-debug.apk' on 'POCO F1 - 8.1.0' for app:debug
Installed on 1 device.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 31s
27 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 26 up-to-date
Running /home/subtleseeker/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb -s 172.26.40.211:8081 reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
error: more than one device/emulator
Could not run adb reverse: Command failed: /home/subtleseeker/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb -s 172.26.40.211:8081 reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
Starting the app on 172.26.40.211:8081 (/home/subtleseeker/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb -s 172.26.40.211:8081 shell am start -n com.awe4/com.awe4.MainActivity)...
Starting: Intent { cmp=com.awe4/.MainActivity }
```

In the `Dev settings` of the app, I have configured `Debug server host & port for device` to the ip address of my computer as `172.26.43.71:8081`. Also it is clear from the output, that the connection was successful and the apk is installed.

I can't see how to resolve this error: `error: more than one device/emulator`. Any help is appreciated.
NOTE: This question may be a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51592477/adb-s-192-168-1-65555-error-more-than-one-device-emulator), but it doesn't have any answers.

Answer (score 4):

When I am facing the same issues than doing like below:

> - Restart adb by issuing **adb kill-server** followed by **adb    start-server** in a command prompt.
> - Disable and re-enable USB debugging on the phone Rebooting the phone    if it still doesn't work.

my issues have been resolved with these steps.

Answer (score 2):

When I am facing the same issues than doing like below:

1) kill your process of 8081 port for using this command : `kill -9 $(lsof -t -i:8081)`

2) Reset your adb connection with : `adb usb` if you want to run via wifi then connect your device again : `adb tcpip 5555`

3) Start your npm : `npm start`

4) Then after you can run your react native app : `react-native run-android`

and it's works fine for me.

Comment: This did not work. Issue remains as described in the question, after these steps.

Comment: Then you need to R&D on port because it is a port-related issue so you need to release one port before using another.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Task Manager]

Open Task Manager > search "qemu" > kill it.
I using Android emulator, work for me! Good luck :)